# Is rails live streaming a good solution for chat?

Tags: android, ruby-on-rails, api, rest, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a rails 4 api used by an android and ios app to exchange JSON.

I want to implement a chat solution between two users. And I don't know what is the best way to achieve that. I see live streaming in rails 4 but I don't know if it's a good thing or not ? I will have potentially hundreds of chat at the same time.
Someone tried to do the same thing ? do you have better solutions to do what I need ? Thanks

Comment: Am I right it would practically mean that you need one Ruby process for each ongoing chat?

Answer (score 0):

Rails live streaming is a so-so solution for chat.  Most tutorials on live controllers use chat as the example.

http://robots.thoughtbot.com/chat-example-app-using-server-sent-events

Keep in mind that you will need a server that support multithreading, such as Puma.

Live applications are resource intensive and have awkward logic.  Using a language that was built for events would be a better route, checkout Angular or GO.

https://angularjs.org/
http://golang.org/